# Cursor/bulk collect

Tags: oracle, plsql

I was trying to display hiredate using lead function with cursor however I'm getting this error message - PLS-00435: DML statement without BULK In-BIND cannot be used inside FORALL. Please guide me.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
DECLARE
CURSOR C_11 IS SELECT * FROM EMP;
TYPE DD IS TABLE OF EMP%ROWTYPE;
CC DD;
VV EMP.HIREDATE%TYPE;
GG EMP.HIREDATE%TYPE;
BEGIN
OPEN C_11;
LOOP
FETCH C_11 BULK COLLECT INTO CC LIMIT 1000;
FORALL I IN CC.FIRST..CC.LAST
SELECT HIREDATE,LEAD(HIREDATE) OVER(ORDER BY HIREDATE) INTO VV,GG FROM EMP;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (VV ||' '||GG);
EXIT WHEN C_11%NOTFOUND;
END LOOP;
CLOSE C_11;
END;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> PLS-00435: DML statement without BULK In-BIND cannot be used inside
>   FORALL.

`FORALL` statement is only used for `INSERT` / `UPDATE` or `DELETE` . It doesnot support `SELECT`.

Read the `FORALL` Restrictions:

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/forall_statement.htm

Alternatively you can do it as shown below:

```
DECLARE
    CURSOR c_11 IS 
      SELECT hiredate,
                   LEAD(hiredate) OVER( ORDER BY  hiredate ) DT           
            FROM emp;

    TYPE dd IS TABLE OF c_11%rowtype;
    cc   dd;
BEGIN
    OPEN c_11;

    LOOP
        FETCH c_11 BULK COLLECT INTO cc LIMIT 100;

        FOR i IN 1..cc.count
        LOOP            
          dbms_output.put_line(cc(i).hiredate || ' -- '  || cc(i).dt);              
       END LOOP;
       EXIT WHEN c_11%notfound;
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE c_11;
END;
```